# MapCircle not rendering in QML when using Mapbox

Tags: qt, qml, mapbox, mapbox-gl, qtlocation

I have an issue with trying to display QML `MapCircle` on a Window when I use the Mapboxgl plugin.

I have a model which is populated from C++ and is shown on the map when the user clicks a button. Here is a snippet:

```
MapItemView{
    model:disksModel
    delegate:MapCircle{
        border.color: "red"
        border.width: 1
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(model.latitude, model.longitude)
        radius: 53
    }
}
```

When I use osm or esri as my plugin,

```
plugin:Plugin{
 name:"esri"
 }
```

I get the following which is what I expect: [image] but using mapbox, the circles aren't displayed. [image]

```
plugin:Plugin{
    name:"mapboxgl"
    PluginParameter {
        name: "mapboxgl.mapping.use_fbo"
        value: true
    }

    PluginParameter {
        name: "mapboxgl.mapping.items.insert_before"
        value: "aerialway"
    }
 }
```

However, if I change my model to use something like a `MapQuickItem` and then use something like a Marker,

```
MapItemView{
    model:disksModel
    delegate:MapQuickItem{
         sourceItem: Image{
            id:waypointMarker
            opacity: .75
            sourceSize.width:80
            sourceSize.height:80
            source: "../images/marker.png"
        }
        coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(model.latitude, model.longitude)
        anchorPoint.x: waypointMarker.width/2
        anchorPoint.y: waypointMarker.height/2
    }
}
```

The coordinates of interest are then marked on the screen
[image]. Does anyone know a workaround or fix for this?

Comment: iirc this was not implemented in the mapboxgl plugin

Comment: aah, that would make sense then, thanks. I guess, I'll just have to wait for updated maps in esri.

Comment: you can also overlap a second map on top, using the "itemsoverlay" plugin, and add circles to that